# MATCH function with #N/D cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-udf

I have the following table in Excel:

```
+----+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
|    |   A    |      B      |     C      |      D      |
+----+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | Month  | Price alpha | Price Beta | Price Gamma |
|  2 | 201601 |             | #DIV/0!    |             |
|  3 | 201602 | 51          | 21         | 93          |
|  4 | 201603 | 47          | 22         | 97          |
|  5 | 201604 | 44          | 28         | 92          |
|  6 | 201605 | 58          | 44         | 98          |
|  7 | 201606 | #N/D        | 28         | 35          |
|  8 | 201607 | #N/D        | 44         | #N/D        |
|  9 | 201608 | #N/D        | #N/D       | #N/D        |
| 10 | 201609 | #N/D        | #N/D       | #N/D        |
| 11 | 201610 | #N/D        | #N/D       | #N/D        |
| 12 | 201611 | #N/D        | #N/D       | #N/D        |
| 13 | 201612 | #N/D        | #N/D       | #N/D        |
+----+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

For each column there is a variable list of numerc values (and, maybe, few *#DIV/0!* errors) and, from a specific rows to the end of the table, only #N/D values.

My goal is to have, for each column, then first Month where the *#N/D* values start.
The results would be:

- Price alpha: 201606
- Price Beta: 201608
- Price gamma: 201607

For this king of tasks I usually write a function cobining **MATCH** and **INDEX** but, unfortunally, the **MATCH** function doesn't accept *#N/D* as value to look for in the matrix.

How could I get the first #N/D error for each column?

Comment: Can you add other columns to the table? You could use `ISNA()` and look for `True`/`False` values.

Comment: @Vinnie it would be better to don't add column (as I'll have more than 180 columns) but if there is not another way it is OK to add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an array function (Ctrl+Shift+Enter).

```
{=MATCH(TRUE,ISNA(A:A),0)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you not putting the #N/D text within quotation marks when using the MATCH  function coupled with the INDEX function: =INDEX(Month,MATCH("#N/D",Price alpha,0),1)? I assume that you have the columns named by the headers.

Comment: The problem is not about the quotation mark. If I write "#N/D" the software only consider the cell where there is "#N/D" as a string of test and not as a result of a formula with error.